# Build additional ZIP with only sources

Tags: maven

Is there a way in Maven to build additionally to the JAR file a ZIP file with only the sources and some text files in it?

I've tried using the assembly plugin for that but it seems it always includes the JAR in the ZIP file.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You use the [Maven Source Plugin](https://maven.apache.org/plugins/maven-source-plugin/index.html) for this purpose.

You can use the [includes](https://maven.apache.org/plugins/maven-source-plugin/jar-mojo.html#includes) parameter to customise exactly what it should include, such as your additional text files.

Comment: Perfect solution, thanks. Wasn't aware that you can include other sources too.

Answer (score 0):

[Maven Assembly plugin](http://maven.apache.org/plugins/maven-assembly-plugin/) can solve this for you. You can configure as many zip artifacts as you want and add to your build process.